# I want to create a HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) Stream using Gstreamer but Audio only

Tags: gstreamer, alsa, http-live-streaming, m3u8, gst-launch

what I want to do is create an `m3u8-file` out of an `alsa soundcard` input.

Like:

```
arecord  hw:1,0 -d 10 test.wav | gst-launch-1.0 ....
```

I tried this for testing:

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! hlssink
```

but it doesn't work.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t create directly HLS video transport segments (.ts) from audio raw source. You need to encode it with some encoder and then mux it before sending to hlssink plugin.

One of the problems that you’ll encounter is that the hlssink plugin won’t split the segments with only audio stream so you are going to need something like **keyunitsscheduler** to split correctly the streams and create the files.

An example pipeline using voaacenc to encode audio and mpegtmux to mux would be as follows:

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc is-live=true ! audioconvert ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! aacparse ! audio/mpeg ! queue ! mpegtsmux ! keyunitsscheduler interval=5000000000 ! hlssink playlist-length=5 max-files=10 target-duration=5 playlist-root="http://localhost/hls/" playlist-location="/var/www/html/hls/stream0.m3u8" location="/var/www/html/hls/fragment%05d.ts"
```

Comment: Did anyone got this working? I get WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "keyunitsscheduler"

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work with hlssink2:

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! avenc_aac ! hlssink2 target-duration=5 max-files=5
```